# Youtube videos are not loading nice on Iphones

Tags: iphone, youtube

Im developing the following site:

http://www.yuco.tv/

Im using the IFrame player API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Videos are encoded as h.264.

But player shows a message saying that current video cannot be displayed.

What really happens is: After one minute first video is not loaded and not autoplayed as in regular computers, but on Iphones works only if you touch the screen like two times, then is played.

I found this on google:

*not all youtube videos are available on the iphone .. they need to be specially encoded 
if you want to try this use safari on your iPhone and go to Youtube.. don't use the default mobile version, you will need to download and use the new browser version.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can verify if the video can be embedded to another web-site by checking "embed" button on YouTube page for this video.

If video is not encoded for embedding so the only way is to hack the original page to download FLV or MP4 for original file and then stream it using your web-site. BUT you should respect copyright holder rights for these videos (in case they do not want to allow their video to play outside youtube)

Comment: What really happens is: After one minute first video is not loaded and not autoplayed as in regular computers, but on Iphones works only if you touch the screen like two times, then is played.